# Change Azure AD registered devices to Joined

Tags: azure, azure-activedirectory

I have a number of Windows 10 devices that have an Azure AD join type as registered. I would like to change the join type to joined. What is the process to achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If I view my devices in Azure AD many of them show their join type as azure ad registered. I would like to change this to azure ad joined for these devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find a lot of misinformation on the internet that to convert devices from AD Registered to AD Joined all you need to do is either join them though autopilot with intune or perform an AAD Join (workplace join) - none of these methods however accomplish the Azure AD joined status if the device already exists as registered.

Most information posted on forums are incorrect.

I have seen a lot of devices that were enrolled to intune,  by importing the hash, performing a systemreset, going through the OOBE, where they succesfully join to Intune and become MDM managed, but still maintain their AD Registered status, and will not process certain policies at only apply to AD Joined devices (such as a policy to tell devices they need to upgrade to win11 from win10, for example)

The best way to accomplish it is to delete all AD Registered devices BEFORE you import their hash file. often though, you may have existing devices that are already enrolled though autopilot, but they are AD Registered still because they already were AD Registered before you imported the hash file.

The following solution does seem to do the trick:

- Delete the device from Intune (Wipe it if you can complete below steps before the computer went through the reset) or just delete it and wipe later from the cmdline.
- Delete the computer from autopilot devices (sometimes this takes several minutes)
- Delete the computer azure ad (this wasn't possible while there was still an autopilot account, but with the autopilot device deleted the trash bin shouldn't be greyed out)
- Re-import the hash file (this will recreate the Azure AD device as JOINED!)
  (You'll notice the Azure AD Device that got created is already Azure AD Joined!)
- Now wipe the device from an elevated command prompt typing system reset (if you didn't initiate the wipe in step 1)

This time around, when the device performs the intune enrollment, it will be both MDM Managed and Azure AD Joined.

It seems that Microsoft should have implemented something to automatically convert AD Registered accounts to AD Joined accounts when they join intune, but actually they haven't.

So the root cause of the whole issue is that devices are alraedy AD Registered before you import the hash, the hash will then map to the existing object, but not change its status to Joined.

So deleting the all 3 objects (intune, autopilot device and azure ad device, in that order) and then doing everything again from scratch, seems to be the only solution to the problem.

I hope someone reads this and complains to Microsoft enough for them to figure out the flaw in this design.

Answer (score 1):

You can provision Azure AD joined devices using the following approaches:

- **Self-service in OOBE/Settings** - In the self-service mode, users go through the Azure AD join process either during Windows Out of Box Experience (OOBE) or from Windows Settings. For more information, see [Join your work device to your organization's network](https://support.microsoft.com/account-billing/join-your-work-device-to-your-work-or-school-network-ef4d6adb-5095-4e51-829e-5457430f3973).
- **Windows Autopilot** - Windows Autopilot enables pre-configuration of devices for a smoother Azure AD join experience in OOBE. For more information, see the [Overview of Windows Autopilot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/windows-autopilot/windows-10-autopilot).
- **Bulk enrollment** - Bulk enrollment enables an administrator driven Azure AD join by using a bulk provisioning tool to configure devices. For more information, see [Bulk enrollment for Windows devices](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/windows-bulk-enroll).
  Here’s a comparison of these three approaches

[image: AAD Join Comparison]

I would recommend you read https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/azureadjoin-plan

Comment: I was probably not clear in my question. If I view my devices in Azure AD many of them show their join type as azure ad registered. I would like to change this to azure ad joined for these devices.

Comment: While you may not have been clear in your question, I was clear in my answer.  You can't just "change" the status from Registered to Joined.  They mean different things.  A registered device is a personally owned machine that is not connected to Azure AD, it is authenticated locally or through AAD.  A joined device is for corporate owned/managed machines that ONLY authenticate through AAD.  You must provision them as outlined above.